# OpenSearchServer stops running: Error (The unique key is missing: content)

Tags: missing-data, unique-key, search-server

I am using OpenSearchServer v1.5.11 - build bd28c79a9d with a total of 5000 home pages. After running the Crawl process (Run forever) I get the following error (4608 pages processed).

> Error (The unique key is missing: content)

The most of the pages in the URL browser section are Unfetched/Not parsed and Not indexed.

What's wrong?

Comment: Was it working before? What code have you tried?

Comment: No, it stops working after 4608 home pages. I added them to the Pattern List.

Is there some possibility to identify which home page is causing the error?

Comment: Setting the url as unique field does the trick.

Comment: Did you know that you can write up the details, post it as an answer, and accept it?